# How does HTTPS transfer the symmetric key?

Tags: tls, openssl

How is the server's public key used to encrypt the symmetric key in a way so that only the sever's private key can decrypt the cipher?

> *The client uses the server’s public key to encrypt the symmetric key and send it securely to the server, and the server uses its private
>   key to decrypt it. Anyone can encrypt using the public key, but only
>   the server can decrypt using the private key.*

Comment: What do you exactly want to know? How the *asymetric* cipher works or how the TLS works? (SSL)

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the cipher suite. **If** the master key is encrypted at all then it is usually encrypted using RSA, which can be identified by ciphersuites starting with `RSA_`. This requires that the certificate that contains the public key allows encryption.

An other way to *establish* the master secret is by using Diffie Hellman key agreement. This usually is ephemeral-ephemeral key agreement; `DHE_` or `ECDHE_` ciphersuites. The ephemeral-static key agreements (`DH_` and `ECDH_`) require certificates containing a Diffie-Hellman public key and these are rare.

Nowadays many certificates only allow authentication, not encryption. They are used together with the aforementioned `DHE_` and `ECDHE_` ciphersuites. In TLS 1.3 the `RSA_` ciphersuites are discontinued as they do not provide *forward security*: if the private key is ever obtained by an adversary then *all* the data of all the TLS sessions becomes available to that adversary.

Note that there are even other ways of authentication possible. The method of using RSA encryption is mainly used for older versions of SSL and TLS. So that description you have is 1. completely over simplified and 2. outdated. Read the TLS 1.2 specification if you want to know more.

Comment: Or our nearby bear's epic https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/